# VS 2010 showing error but run the program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

When i run my program in opencv c++ visual studio 2010 the program run but i show the following error's , What this error want to install further more ?

```
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WK01\Debug\WK01.exe', Symbols loaded.
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast5\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opencv_core244d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opencv_highgui244d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opencv_ffmpeg244.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WK01.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[4156] WK01.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not errors, they are just informational messages from the debugger.

When a program is compiled in Debug mode (and optionally in Release mode), a `.pdb` file is also produced, that associates function names and variable names in the source code with the corresponding locations in the compiled code. It's this information that Visual Studio uses to show you source code and variable values as you step through the program.

All that's happening here is that your program is running in the debugger and is loading system DLLs and other modules that don't have a `.pdb` file, so it's telling you that it won't be able to show equivalent source code for these modules.

Summary. It's normal, not an error.